# How to Add a PHP if Statement Into a HTML String

Tags: php

I want to add the checked attribute (checked="checked") to an input if the value of some user meta data is true. But I don't know the correct syntax to do this when working within a HTML string. Here's my current syntax:

```
$html = '' .
    '<h3>User Committees</h3>' . 
    '<table class="form-table">' . 
        '<tr>' .
            '<td>' .
                '<label>' .
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="conference_&_sponsorship" value="1" ' . if ( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'conference_&_sponsorship', true) == 'true') { 'checked' } . '>' .
                    'Conference & Sponsorship' .
                '</label>' .
            '</td>' .
        '</tr>' .
    '</table>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Use ternary operator as advised by @u_mulder. Or consider using some templating engine (like Smarty or Latte) instead.

Comment: Please show what you tried...

Comment: I don't know what you two are looking at but I've clearly put my code in the question showing what I've tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ternary operator will help you:

```
$html = '' .
    '<label>' .
        '<input type="checkbox" name="conference_&_sponsorship" value="1" ' . ( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'conference_&_sponsorship', true) == 'true' ? 'checked' : '' ) . '>' .
        'Conference & Sponsorship' .
    '</label>';

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is PHP (not Sparta), so just use a multiline string, I get goosebumps seeing your code :)

```
$checked = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'conference_&_sponsorship', true) ? 'checked' : '';

$html = '
    <h3>User Committees</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="conference_&_sponsorship" value="1" '.$checked.'">
                    Conference & Sponsorship
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
';

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always seperate it like this:

```
$html = '' .
    '<h3>User Committees</h3>' . 
    '<table class="form-table">' . 
        '<tr>' .
            '<td>' .
                '<label>' .
                    '<input type="checkbox" name="conference_&_sponsorship" value="1" ';


   if ( get_user_meta($user->ID, 'conference_&_sponsorship', true) == 'true') { $html .= 'checked'; } 
   $html .= '>' .
                            'Conference & Sponsorship' .
                        '</label>' .
                    '</td>' .
                '</tr>' .
            '</table>';

        echo $html;
```